# preg_match_all pattern html tag issue

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

There are 4 different img tag

```
<img src="img1.jpg" alt="test" />
<img src="img2.jpg" height="21"/>
<img src="img3.jpg" border="1">
<img src="img4.jpg" >
```

I use PHP code

```
preg_match_all('#<img (.*?)([/>| />|>| >])#si',$this->Data,$img);
```

but This PHP code result

```
Array
  (
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => src="img1.jpg"
        [1] => src="img2.jpg"
        [2] => src="img3.jpg"
        [3] => src="img4.jpg"

    )
```

I want to result :

```
    Array
  (
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => src="img1.jpg" alt="test"
        [1] => src="img2.jpg" height="21"
        [2] => src="img3.jpg" border="1"
        [3] => src="img4.jpg"

    )
```

Can you help me pls ?

Comment: Try removing the space after (.*?)

Comment: `#<img (.*?)(/>| />|>| >)#si`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
preg_match_all('#<img (.*?)\s?/?>#is', $this->Data, $img);
```

the `\s?` optionally matches white space sollowed by a optional slash `/?`.

this will essentially get any content from a well formed img tag. (assuming you don't have any > in the values for the attributes).

as something to keep in mind, regex is not the correct tool for parsing html - but for small - limited - matches it is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like giving what you want;

```
$s = '<img src="img1.jpg" alt="test" />
      <img src="img2.jpg" height="21"/>
      <img src="img3.jpg" border="1">
      <img src="img4.jpg" >';
preg_match_all('~<img\s+(.+?)([\s/>]|)>~i', $s, $m);
print_r($m);
```

Out;

```
Array
(
    ...
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => src="img1.jpg" alt="test" 
            [1] => src="img2.jpg" height="21"
            [2] => src="img3.jpg" border="1"
            [3] => src="img4.jpg" 
        )
```

By thet way, as far as I know, you don't need to use `s` flag for `preg_match_all`, cos of it's matching `*_all`.

Comment: I don't get that last sentence.  There's no conflict/overlap between the `s` modifier and the `preg_match_all` method.  I suspect you're thinking of the `g` flag that's used in Perl, JavaScript, and some other flavors to specify a global match.  PHP doesn't support the `g` flag; it uses `preg_match_all` for that.